# Creating a dropdown list with enum?

Tags: mysql, yii2

How do I create a from dropdown holding values from enum in the specific column of the database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how gii generator works:

```
$model = new MyModel; // this is your model
$tableSchema = $model->getTableSchema();
$column = $tableSchema->columns['my_column']; // the column that has enum values

if (is_array($column->enumValues) && count($column->enumValues) > 0) {
    $dropDownOptions = [];
    foreach ($column->enumValues as $enumValue) {
        $dropDownOptions[$enumValue] = \yii\helpers\Inflector::humanize($enumValue);
    }
}
```

this will generate you `$dropDownOptions` with the enum values.